# Get the running gradle task name

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I use gradle splits to generate different apks for different architectures. However, based on the running "assemble(ABI)" I'd like to disable building some native libraries.

My question is, if I run:
gradle assembleMipsDebug 
how can I get "assembleMipsDebug" or preferably "mips" from build.gradle script?

Comment: You don't.

A Gradle build script does not build software. It builds an *object model* of how to build software. At the time the script is run -- such as when Android Studio opens your project -- there is no "running Gradle task".

Comment: how can I control the "splits" to ensure that I only build what I want?

Comment: AFAIK, you don't. This should be separate product flavors, if I had to guess.

Comment: That's what I thought too! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have splits enabled, there is no separate gradle task for each ABI. Still, you can provide different options for different splits.

You can choose the list of built libraries in your **Android.mk** or **CMakeLists.txt** script, or you can list the explicit **targets** in the [externalNativeBuild](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeBuildOptions.html) block.